# Removing/storing old users in SBS 2003

Tags: domain, windows-sbs-2003

I am new when it comes to some of the things on a domain server, but I was wondering what are some thoughts on how long to keep old users accounts on a SBS setting. I currently have around 10 users that haven't worked here in over a year and would like to remove them from the user lists if I can.

I was wondering what best practices are for this type of situation.

(All users are deactivated, but emails are forwarding to respective department heads)

Thanks for the assistance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first off, just leaving them in a disabled state isn't going to hurt anything, so there's nothing wrong with just leaving them alone.  It also sounds like you've got a pretty small environment (SBS), so the extra "clutter" from disabled users shouldn't be causing you much trouble.

Having said that, what I like to do in my ADs, provided the suits are willing, is set some policies and procedures around what to do with ex-employees' accounts, and how long they get to exist after the person is gone.  Generally, I'll create an OU that disabled accounts go into and run a scheduled task or script to clean out any objects older than x days.  Regarding email, in addition to forwarding it to their department heads, setting an automatic reply to the effect that they no longer work here and email should go to [blah] instead helps calm objections to old accounts eventually being deleted.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, it's not a lot of "clutter" as we are small, but I was looking at this from a future standpoint. I am implementing rules and policies that would carry through for a few years of expansion.